# Sitecore rocks automation

Tags: tds, sitecore-rocks

Anyone know a way to automate sitecore rocks with TDS package building?

I've tried to create a solution where I read the pending TFS TDS items to get a list of sitecore .item files that are new or have updated. However, this needs to run with a sitecore context. I put the DLL into the instance but get a database configuration node error. Thought I might be able to create a sitecore rocks extension, but documentation seems, well, scant!

My end goal is to do a bunch of sitecore development and build any changed TFS .item files into a . update package with minimum fuss .. ie, click a single button!

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve delta deploys? There is alreadt a possibility in TDS. Take a look in this article -> http://reyrahadian.com/2017/10/20/how-tds-git-delta-deploy-make-my-life-easier/

Comment: Yeah, kind of, but TDS has some limitations as it only works on the _updated field. Normally this is fine, but sometimes due to the choppy/changey nature of the project, I might create templates etc. say 6 weeks ago, shelve it, make more changes, then unshelve. I then find myself in a situation where a) I'm not sure when to set the changed after date and b) has more in it than I want to deploy

Comment: I think you're looking for TDS Git Delta Deploy instead. “Yet another Hedgehog Team Development for Sitecore setup, from Developer Workstation to CI / CD…” by Vincent Lui https://link.medium.com/U0eOYo7gtT

Comment: Hey Vincent, looks like there could be elements in there that I could maybe pick out and utilize (specifically Hedgehog Package Installer). We're using TFS, not git, so I'll need some more research... but interesting article that could end up being used. ty

Comment: It should be possible. I never investigated TFS Delta Deploy as it's use is quite low compared to git. As long as you can execute commands to return changed files, it shouldn't be a terrible lift to convert Git Delta Deploy to TFS Delta Deploy. Search "GitDiff" to see where the commands are run: https://github.com/SaintSkeeta/TDS.BuildExtensions.GitDeltaDeploy/blob/master/src/_Nuget/build/Hedgehog.TDS.BuildExtensions.GitDeltaDeploy.targets

Comment: Managed to cobble something together using MS Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools (has powershell to tfs-getpendingchange) and a hacked up custom version of HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.PackageBuilder.exe. It isn't pretty but it's effective! :-)